# How to save a shell-script-printout within python script in list or array?

Tags: python, list, shell, output

I want to run the shell command within python script. And save the printout in a list or array.

for example the print out of shell command is as below

```
root@cic-1:~# for i in $(neutron net-list | grep -i cscf2 | awk '{print $2}'); do neutron net-show $i | grep -i segmentation|awk '{print $4}' ; done
2006
2022
2023
2081
root@cic-1:~#
```

I want this printout to be saved in a list like this

[2006,2022,2023,2081]

I have done the python code as below

```
#!/usr/pkg/bin/python
import subprocess

vlans= subprocess.Popen ("for i in $(neutron net-list | grep -i cscf2 | awk '{print $2}'); do neutron net-show $i | grep -i segmentation|awk '{print $4}' ; done", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print vlans[0]
```

the output is 2 , However I want vlans[0] be 2006

Comment: Looks like you want the file content of `vlans.stdout` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)). I wouldn't know how to use it (not strong in Python), but this is what I found googling around

Comment: I have tried that using stdout.read() but still that does not work.

Comment: The issue is that the all printout saved as one long string

Answer (score 1):

If you want `vlans[0]` to be the first line of the output, then the output needs to be split into lines.  To do this, I added `.split('\n')` to the end of the `vlans = ...` command:

```
>>> vlans= subprocess.Popen ('printf "%s\n" 2006 2022 2023 2081', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')
>>> vlans
['2006', '2022', '2023', '2081', '']
>>> vlans[0]
'2006'
```

Since, of course, I don't have `neutron` or `net-list`, I substituted another shell command which gives the same output that you show.

#### Improvement

Shell output typically includes a final newline.  When python's `split` function sees that final newline, however, it creates a final empty string.  To eliminate that, we can apply `strip` to the output before passing it to `split`:

```
>>> vlans= subprocess.Popen ('printf "%s\n" 2006 2022 2023 2081', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip().split('\n')
>>> vlans
['2006', '2022', '2023', '2081']
>>> vlans[0]
```

Depending on your goals, you may want to use `rstrip('\n')` in place of the more hungry `strip()`.

Comment: What is the last empty value ' ' ? why is that added to the list ?

Comment: @ne9een Good observation.  I  updated the answer with a discussion of that and included a way to eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess.check_output to (more) easily capture the output of the command.  This is functionally equivalent to what you have.

```
vlans = subprocess.check_output(
    "for i in $(neutron net-list | grep -i cscf2 | awk '{print $2}'); "
    "do neutron net-show $i | grep -i segmentation|awk '{print $4}' ; done")
```

If you want the vlans as a list of strings you can do this:

```
vlans = vlans.splitlines()
```

If you want a list of integers do this instead:

```
vlans = [int(v) for v in vlans.splitlines()]
```

Comment: File "Brad.py", line 3, in <module>
    vlans = subprocess.check_output("for i in $(neutron net-list | grep -i cscf2 | awk '{print $2}'); do neutron net-show $i | grep -i segmentation|awk '{print $4}' ; done")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory